# Why Assembly and Activator behave differently for CreateInstance

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm writing some code to dynamically create some objects (of an unknown type), and I am curious why Activator is able to generate the type, but Assembly is not.
Here is a code sample:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Type t = typeof (int);
        object notAnInt = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance(t.FullName);//does not work
        object actualInt = Activator.CreateInstance(t);//works

        Console.WriteLine(notAnInt);
        Console.WriteLine(actualInt);
    }
}
```

My question is why are these two behaving differently when I would imagine they should both be able to create an instance of an int?

Comment: **How** does it not work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Assembly.CreateInstance` creates an instance of a type *in that assembly*.

`System.Int32` is not defined in your assembly.

To make that work, you need to get the `Assembly` for mscorlib.
For example, you can write `typeof(Assembly).Assembly`

Answer (score 0):

Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() gets your exe or dll (the assembly that is currently executing actually). Since Int32 is defined in mscorlib and not in your exe or dll , Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CreateInstance() will return null. To get int type object using CreateInstance, try the below code:

```
var intTypeAssembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(t);
object iAmAnInt = intTypeAssembly.CreateInstance(t.FullName);
```